# iPhone 6plus freezes and unresponsive

Tags: ios, performance, iphone

I have an iPhone 6 plus 128 gb and it is running iOS 8.1.3. The phone was never broken.

I noticed after the latest firmware update that it hangs and becomes unresponsive. Whenever that happens a black tent of shade covers the screen. The home button doesn't work the lock of the screen doesn't work. I always have to restart the phone.

Has anyone else experienced the same?

Comment: You might want to try restoring the phone via iTunes. If that doesn't work perhaps take it to an apple store. But this sounds like a software issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experienced this, but I would highly recommend reinstalling the latest iOS (iOS 8.2) onto it, by using a computer with iTunes and hooking your phone to the computer with the USB data cable.

In iTunes, it should detect an update available and ask if you would like to update.  Go ahead and update it that way.  If that doesn't work, manually download the iOS 8.2 firmware update for your device from [IPSW Downloads](https://ipsw.me) and then, with your phone plugged into the computer via the USB Data cable, and iTunes open, hold down the shift or control key while clicking on "Update" on iTunes.  This will open a file selection dialog/window, then just select the file you downloaded (iOS 8.2 Firmware file that you downloaded from ipsw.me), and it will flash your phone with the latest version.

Hopefully this will take care of the issue.

If not, you may have to take it to an Apple store and have them fix it/replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem with my I phone 6 freezing. Went to the Apple Store they tried a few fixes didn t work. Then they removed the screen saver, presto all is well

Comment: There is no screensaver on iPhone.

Comment: The parallax lock screen perhaps ?